# How to redirect via web.config ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I need to redirect from example.com/landing to example.com/blog/info/landing.
I wrote a rule in web.config

```
<rule name="Atlanta redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="landing" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/blog/info/landing" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

but if url matches "landing" word then it redirect to example.com/blog/info/landing too.

For example correct redirect:
example.com/landing -> example.com/blog/info/landing

Wrong redirect
example.com/somepage/1/landing -> example.com/blog/info/landing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex that matches `/landing` exactly:

```
<match url="^landing$" />
```

(IIS removes the leading `/` when doing regex matches)

The `^` and `$` symbols are Regex Anchors that match the start and end of the string respectively.